# How do you distinguish between FontAwesome's circles?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, icons, font-awesome

I am rendering an icon in my React Native app, and have to specify the checked/unchecked icon type. I am reading the list of FontAwesome icons here: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=circle

There are many different circle icons called "circle". When I specify "circle" as the icon type in my app, it uses the [filled circle](https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=solid) by default, but I want to use the [outline circle](https://fontawesome.com/icons/circle?style=regular). Does anyone know how to do this? Specifically, I am rendering a <[CheckBox](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html)> component and specifying the `uncheckedType` field.

Answer (score 0):

I’d recommend using `react-native-vector-icons` which includes FontAwesome. Check out the directory of all the icon packs [here](https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/).

That all have unique names, so the code would look something like this:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

const checked = <Icon name="circle" size={30} color="#900" />;

const unchecked = <Icon name=“circle-o” size={30} color={#900} />;
```

This will make it really easy to quickly add all kinds of icons into your app!